# added data don't update automatically in useEffect() Need refresh browser to get the last addition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a trouble in small app. I have one component that add data to db. Works well. In other component I fetch the data inside useEffect() and make a search from db. As well works well. The two components are returned in my App.js. The problem is that when I add data and go to search I need to refresh the page for search the last adding. So if I don't refresh the page it doesn't find it. How to solve this?  (a bit explained if possible) :)

From component Search.js

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get("http://localhost:3004/api/list/").then(resp=>{
            console.log(resp.data)
            setList(resp.data) ;
        })
    },[])
```

From component

````
const AddData = () =>{
    const [name, setName] = useState();
    const [tel, setTel] = useState();
    const [gender, setGender] = useState();
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // starting to work to save input to DB via API 
        //  dispatch(addList(name,tel,gender));
        dispatch(addList(name,tel,gender))
    }
    return(
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Because of the empty dependency array, useEffect runs only once like componentDidUpdate.

Comment: If not empty dependency array it will produce an infinite loop. So how any idea how to solve this?

Comment: 1. create a function say getData() for ex.
2. Put axios.get() inside this newly created function.
3. Call this Function from useEffect and addData() as well.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency array can't be empty, you either put something in there or get rid of the dependency array.

Comment: the array must be there, and can be empty. If not produce infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed. I deleted the useEffect() and create a function with the same Axios getting list. I call the function when typing the search. It works. Thx guys for your answers. They were very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your search as state e.g.

```
const{query, setQuery} = useState('')
```

Then when you search setQuery('my-search-term')

Then useEffect but add state to the dependency array so every time that bit of state is updated it fires the axios request

```
useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get("http://localhost:3004/api/list/").then(resp=>{
            console.log(resp.data)
            setList(resp.data) ;
        })
    },[query])
```